# Azure Website - Query Azure Database with REST

Tags: javascript, rest, azure, azure-sql-database

I currently have a basic html/js/css web app being hosted on Microsoft Azure. What I need to do next is pull some data an Azure SQL database onto one of the pages using REST calls.

Does anyone know what steps I need to take in order to accomplish this?

Comment: Not sure what your actual question is. If it's accessing SQL Database from your app, you'll need a proper driver (there's no REST API for SQL Server). If it's about providing your own REST API to the outside world, that's a really broad question with no right answer, and off-topic - lots of ways to implement, lots of ways to host it.

Comment: Thanks David! This area is fairly new to me and I appreciate your insight. When I have built web apps in the past, the backend was MS SharePoint and way I would grab data from lists is making a REST call out to the site and put it on the page. I was hoping to do the same way with some SQL tables I have created. By driver, do you mean some kind of "API Service" I need to create for my SQL Database? I know it is possible to use REST on SQL databases; I just don't know how to setup something like this in Azure (or somewhere else if needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built my own Web API in VS 2015 for my database and deployed it to azure that way. See reference below:

http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2015/06/05/a-step-by-step-guide-to-working-with-the-asp-net-web-api-and-angularjs.aspx

Comment: Sorry, but your link is broken.  I admire your enthusiasm to build your own Web API, but still I am baffled... WHY IS THIS NECESSARY???  For the Azure Table storage, or Blob, or Files, you don't have to write your own web api (just use OData).  And for Azure Cosmos you don't have to write your own web api (just use OData).  Even Sharepoint has OData interface to it's data.  Why not Azure SQL???

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too board. There are many ways can satisfy your requirement. Generally speaking, you need to build a backend service to connect to your SQL Database and provide REST APIs service.

On Azure, you can quickly acquire this via [Web Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-overview/) or [API Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-apps-why-best-platform/). However, all the operations to Azure SQL database need you to implement by yourself depend on which develop language you are using. You can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-get-started/ for more details.

Comment: Hi Gary! Yes, I fully agree about my question. Before I asked this question, my understanding on how APIs really work wasn't very clear to me. However, after doing a lot of research and learning, I was able to come up with a solution by building "Web API" project for my database in VS 2015 and deploy it to Azure. Thanks for your help!